# Perform Tesseract OCR on entire directory with python

Tags: python, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

I have Multiple number of Images in directory and want to convert it from images to text files. I have to do it manually in terminal one by one. which is headache process. SO, my question is how can i run my code on that folder which contain images.

> Here is the terminal command to convert it into text :

```
convert captcha.png -resize 200% -type Grayscale input.tif  #instead of input.tif i want same file name so, i can recognise easily 

tesseract -l eng input.tif output  #output name as same as file name
```

Comment: use pytesseract & glob

Comment: i tried that but image to text results are quite horrible this works perfect for me . is there any way ?

Comment: Use `subprocess.call` to call the shell command on various files, and use glob to find the files names.

Comment: Still can't figure it out how to do it . but still thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your OS? Windows? OSX? Linux?

Comment: Mac OS  X is my OS @xenoid

Comment: @xenoid  help me guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler method, no Python, just using two terminal commands, one that converts all the files to TIFF, and one that calls tesseract on each TIFF file:

1. Convert all your images to TIFF

   ```
   convert '*.png' -resize 200% -type Grayscale +adjoin -set filename:name "%t" '%[filename:name].tif'
   ```
2. Call tesseract on the results:

   ```
   for f in *.tif;do tesseract -l eng "$f" "$(basename "$f" .tif).txt";done
   ```

   (you can skip the double quotes (`"`) if there are no spaces in your file names.

Replacement for step 1) if output names look weird:

```
for f in *.png;do convert "$f" -resize 200% -type Grayscale "$(basename "$f" .png).tif";done
```

Comment: Filename will look like this `['603351234'].tif` @xenoid

Comment: @wizard Not for me. Added alternative one-liner for the `convert` step in the answer.